# Replace current URL without redirecting

Tags: javascript

Basically I have 3 pages.

1. Homepage
2. Attempt page
3. Redirect page

When the user clicks on Attempt button, he is forwarded to Redirect page which opens a popup window for him using,

```
window.open('Foo.jsp', 'mywindow', 'status=1,toolbar=0');
```

Then i redirect him to Attempt page again on the original window. I used,

```
window.location.replace("Attempt.jsp");
```

to remove Redirect Page history.
But now when the user clicks back button of browser, again Attempt.jsp opens. I want him to navigate to Homepage when he clicks on BACK button of browser. How do i achieve this?

> HOMEPAGE -> ATTEMPT -> REDIRECT(Opens Popup and then redirects to
>   Attempt) -> ATTEMPT(User is here now)

Now when user clicks Browser BACK button, he should go back to HOMEPAGE.
If i can replace url of ATTEMPT PAGE when the user first arrives, then maybe i can achieve this.

Comment: `history.pushState()`

Comment: Can you explain a little, because I'm much into Java rather than Javascript. I have read about pushState() but could not understand it properly. A little more hint would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the user have to go through the attempt page to get to the redirect page initially?

Can you simply make the button on the homepage take them to the redirect page directly which when using window.location.replace() will remove the redirect page from history and make the back button on the attempt page take them back to the homepage?

Comment: The Attempt Page shows the user what he is going to Attempt, Redirect page is used to open Popup window and do some JSP related operations on Redirect.

Comment: How do you forward the user from attempt to redirect? You could try doing window.location.replace from it to redirect too.

Comment: I am currently redirecting the user via a Servlet..
Edit: The button is a Submit button whose action is a Servlet. The Servlet then redirects using response.sendRedirect("Redirect.jsp");