# location.replace to remove history of current page without redirecting?

Tags: javascript

I had recently posted a question regarding my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643371/replace-current-url-without-redirecting).

When i click on a SUBMIT BUTTON or a LINK, I do not want the history of the page where the user clicked the BUTTON or LINK to get recorded in browser.

I received a suggestion to use `history.pushState()`. But I am not familiar with the function and I urgently need the solution to work.

I still not sure as to what to do. But can anyone suggest me whether I can use this to solve my problem.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="location.replace(this.href); return false;"/>

<a href="foo.jsp" onclick="location.replace(this.href); return false;">Continue</a>
```

Example : I have a page `bar.html` which has a link `<a href="foo.html">Foo</a>`. When the user clicks on the link, he should be redirected to `foo.html` and browser history of `bar.html` should not get recorded so that the user cannot use BACK button to get back on this page.

**Edit:** Also how can I force the browser not to store a certain page in cache, so the next time user visits, the browser requests the server for the page.

Comment: If youre not familiar with it, read about it, try some things, and let us know how it goes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: I have tried `window.history.go(-1)` and a couple of other things but I don't know whether this can be done or not.

Answer (score 0):

For chnage page with JS, use code like this:

```
<a href="foo.jsp" onclick="location.href=this.href; return false;">Continue</a>
```

But i don't sure about it history work.

Comment: `replace()` does remove the history.. But i can't make it work. I am not familiar with javascript. So am stuck on this.

Comment: replace is the method of string, location is object, not string

Comment: `replace()` can be used with `location` also. [Refer this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example:

File: **a.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>A</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A</h1>
    <a href="b.html">B</a>
</body>
</html>
```

File: **b.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>B</title>
    <script>
        window.location.replace('c.html');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>B</h1>
    <a href="c.html">C</a>
</body>
</html>
```

File: **c.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>B</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>C</h1>
</body>
</html>
```